# Is it possible to get the entire result of bash brace expansion between double quotes?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I would like to use Bash brace expansion and get the final result quoted between double quotes:

I managed to get that result only by using `seq` as follows:

```
echo '"'$(seq 1 5)'"';
```

output (This is the expected output):

```
"1 2 3 4 5"
```

However when I try only brace expansion:

```bsh
echo '"'{1..5}'"'
```

But unfortunately that results in:

```
"1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Is it possible to get the same result as above (using `seq` command) but only using bash brace expansion (without external commands)?

Answer (score 2):

Like so? (With Bash's `echo`)

```
$ echo -n \"; echo -n {1..5}; echo \"
```

Or (assuming default `IFS`):

```
$ quoteme() { printf \"; printf "$*"; printf '"\n'; }
$ quoteme {1..5}
"1 2 3 4 5"
```